# How to lower polycount

Tags: cycles-render-engine, topology, polycount

i have created a grenade for game use in blender, and it has 4,449 vertices. Using decimate, i brought it down from 45K vertices. But i don't know if 4,449 vertices is low enough for a game, and if not, how else will i reduce poly count? Any feedback would be appreciated. this is for A FPS game

Comment: When choosing poly/vert count, you need to consider 1. What platform you are running on (mobile/pc/console etc), 2. How many other ploys from other objects are likely to be in the scene 3. How closely will the player see the object /how much focus is the player going to have on the object. Even then the exact numbers are changing, and performance is affected by many other factors, so you will likely want to make a few test scenes.

Answer (score 1):

This answer can only give you the starting points for further research and learning. Google the terms I mention and read up on them, much has been written and there are many tutorials out there if you look for these key words.

For most cases you would be better off cutting it down to maybe 200 vertices or less, assuming you're not right in front of the grenade the whole time.

Generally you will want to take your high-poly version as a reference and build a **retopology** mesh from it, then transfer the fine details onto the low-resolution model by **baking** them into a **normal map**.

The decimate modifier will usually not yield good topology alone, but it is useful for a fast LevelOfDetail generation.